# Declaration of a Class in different ways

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, class, c#-4.0

Have class Called "  DiffClass "

```
 public class DiffClass
 {
     public int a;
     public int b;
 }
```

Wanted to know what is difference declaring the DiffClass below :

```
 DiffClass c = new DiffClass();
            c.a = 2;
            c.b = 3;

 DiffClass d = new DiffClass() { a = 2, b = 3 };
```

Comment: you have only one class (but try to declare two instances - i guess), ...

Comment: This is not "declaring DiffClass". You're declaring, and assigning `c` and `d` variables and creating an instance of `DiffClass`.

Answer (score 0):

They are same, second one will be compiled into a code that is pretty similar to first one, something like this:

```
DiffCLass temp = new DiffClass();
temp.a = 2;
temp.b = 3;

DiffClass d = temp;
```